# C++ map no matching member function for call to 'find' when used for a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, dictionary, find

I'm getting below error when I try using find function for map<string,string> datatype, not what I'm missing

error

```
Line 20: Char 29: error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
                auto it = b.find(s[i]);
                          ~~^~~~
```

```
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValid(string s) {
       int l = s.length();
    map<string,string> b;
        b["("] = ")";
        b["{"] = "}";
        b["["] = "]";

        vector<string> br;
        if(l%2 == 1)
            return false;
        else {
            for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
                auto it = b.find(s[i]);  \\ line where error is pointed 
                if(it != b.end() && br.size()==0){
                    return false;   
                }
                else if(it != b.end() && br.size()>0){
                    if(br.rbegin() == s[i]){
                        br.pop_back();
                    }
```

Comment: `s[i]` is a `char`. `find()` of a map containing strings expects a string

Comment: `if(br.rbegin() == s[i])` isn't going to do what you think it is either, or rather it won't even compile. I vote to close as a result of a typo (or multiple).

Comment: Unlike Python, where `'a'` and `"a"` are the same thing, a single character (`'a'`) is not the same as a one-character string (`"a"`) in C++. It looks like you actually want a `map<char, char>`.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter type of the member function `find` of the class `std::map<std::string, std::string>` is `const std::string &`.
However you are using an argument of the type char and there is no implicit conversion from the type char to the type `std::string`.

```
auto it = b.find(s[i]);
```

So you need to convert explicitly the argument to the type `std::string` or provide an object of a type that can be implicitly converted to the type std::string.

For example before the call above you could declare a character array like

```
const char item[] = { s[i], '\0' };
```

and then write

```
auto it = b.find( item );
```

Or without the auxiliary character array you could just write

```
auto it = b.find( std::string ( 1, s[i]) );
```

In any case it is unclear why you are using the type `std::map<std::string, std::string>` instead of `std::map<char, char>`.

Pay attention to that your code has other errors.

For example in this statement

```
if(br.rbegin() == s[i]){
```

there is an attempt to compare an iterator with an object of the type char.

Maybe you mean a vector of the type

```
vector<char> br;
```

instead of the vector of the type

```
vector<string> br;
```

In this case you could write the above shown if statement like

```
if( *br.rbegin() == s[i]){
```

Comment: Hey, I initially used a map<char,char> but when I tried using find method for the map indexed by keys from string 's' it showed a different error, so I changed the map type. thanks for the initial fix @VladfromMoscow